# Android GPS: measured distance between locations continiously

Tags: android, gps

I want to create an application of distance tracker in android. I have a `Spinner, button` and a `TextView`.
Initially text view will be **0.00km**.
When I click the button (GPS tracking start) and start walking in the text view it will show the distance continuously. When I click the button again(GPS tracking terminate) and show the full distance between clicking button.

Here is the screenshot that the application will look like:

[image: starting app]

[image: after click start button]

Here is My Code:

```
public class Gps extends Activity   {

 TextView display;


  double currentLon=0 ;
  double currentLat=0 ;
  double lastLon = 0;
  double lastLat = 0;
  double distance;




public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);


  LocationManager lm =(LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
                lm.requestLocationUpdates(lm.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,0, Loclist);
                Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.GPS_PROVIDER);

                if(loc==null){
                    display.setText("No GPS location found");
                    }
                    else{
                        //set Current latitude and longitude
                        currentLon=loc.getLongitude();
                        currentLat=loc.getLatitude();

                        }
                //Set the last latitude and longitude
                lastLat=currentLat;
                lastLon=currentLon ;


}



 LocationListener Loclist = new LocationListener(){




@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     //start location manager
     LocationManager lm =(LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

      //Get last location
     Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.GPS_PROVIDER);

    //Request new location
      lm.requestLocationUpdates(lm.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,0, Loclist);

      //Get new location
      Location loc2 = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.GPS_PROVIDER);

      //get the current lat and long
     currentLat = loc.getLatitude();
     currentLon = loc.getLongitude();


    Location locationA = new Location("point A");
        locationA.setLatitude(lastLat);
        locationA.setLongitude(lastLon);

    Location locationB = new Location("point B");
        locationB.setLatitude(currentLat);
        locationB.setLongitude(currentLon);

        double distanceMeters = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);

        double distanceKm = distanceMeters / 1000f;

        display.setText(String.format("%.2f Km",distanceKm ));

        }



@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



}

 };

}
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: please do post your code

Comment: @MDMalik,now I edited my post. In here, when app start it calculate distance. But I need, when I click start button then it calculate distance and when click stop button it will give the full distance and gps tracking will stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should register a listener on the GPS when the location changed. You basically have to store the previous known location and compare it with the new one.

The simplest way to get the distance between two points would be to use:

```
sqrt( (x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2 + (z2 - z1)^2 )
```

- X may be the latitude
- Y may be the longitude
- Z may be the altitude

Here is a pseudo code sample to help you

```
public class GpsCalculator
{

    private LocationManager locationManager = null;
    private Location previousLocation = null;
    private double totalDistance = 0D;

    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 100; // 100 meters
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minutes

    public void run(Context context)
    {
        // Get the location manager
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Service.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Add new listeners with the given params
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, locationListener); // Network location
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, locationListener); // Gps location
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    }

    private LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location newLocation)
        {
            if (previousLocation != null)
            {
                double latitude = newLocation.getLatitude() + previousLocation.getLatitude();
                latitude *= latitude;
                double longitude = newLocation.getLongitude() + previousLocation.getLongitude();
                longitude *= longitude;
                double altitude = newLocation.getAltitude() + previousLocation.getAltitude();
                altitude *= altitude;
                GpsCalculator.this.totalDistance += Math.sqrt(latitude + longitude + altitude);
            }

            // Update stored location
            GpsCalculator.this.previousLocation = newLocation;
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };
}
```

And the Activty should look like that:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private Button mainButton = null;
    private boolean isButtonPressed = false;

    private GpsCalculator gpsCalculator = null;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);

        // Create a new GpsCalculator instance
        this.gpsCalculator =  new GpsCalculator();

        // Get your layout + buttons

        this.mainButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.main_button);

        this.mainButton.addOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick()
            {
                // Enable or diable gps
                if (MainActivity.this.isButtonPressed) gpsCalculator.run(this);
                else gpsCalculator.stop();

                // Change button state
                MainActivity.this.isButtonPressed = !MainActivity.this.isButtonPressed;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please tell me how can i initially stop gps tracking and when i click start button, then gps tracking will start. Plz help me.

Comment: How can I stop gps tracker when button pressed?

Comment: You could use `locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);` to stop the GPS. You can then restart the GPS with `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, locationListener);`

Comment: Suppose I have one button, initially the button label is "start", when I click the button label will be "stop" and GPS tracking will start. Then when I click that button again, this will go to the next activity, is it possible?

Comment: You could increment a counter when the user clicks on the button. If the counter is equals `0` it means it's the first time he presses it, so we start the tracker and change the button label. The counter will equal `1`. Then if the user presses it, you'll change the label to 'Stop' and increment the counter. And finally, if he presses it again, you'll change the activity.

Comment: Thank you very much. Last Question, can you check my code that I added. The calculated distence is not perfect. Some times when i click start, it shows 1550.0km. I don't know why. Is there any code that I get the update of distance in my text view after every 100 meters.

Comment: You are using the last known location, which obviously can be far from your current one. I suggest you to remove it and only start to count when and only when the GPS signal hss been successfully hooked.

Comment: I can not do that.How can I start count? Can you plz give me the solution. It will be very helpful for me.